Setting up a Vertx Proxy Server with OAuth2 sign in
How do I route the urls correctly for the following?
I have created a Vertx Reverse Proxy for the purposes of authenticating a legacy web app that was setup a very long time ago.
The web app sits and runs on port 8200. I have created the reverse proxy on 8201.  I have registered the application in the Azure Active Directory and setup a callback route but I think I may have the routes configured wrong.
I want to protect all calls through the proxy with OAuth2 to the backend server.
v = Vertx.vertx();

        HttpClient proxyClient = v.createHttpClient();
        HttpProxy httpProxy = HttpProxy.reverseProxy(proxyClient);
        Router proxyRouter = Router.router(v);
        
        HttpServer proxyServer = v.createHttpServer();

        OAuth2Auth authProvider = AzureADAuth.create(v, "CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET", "TENANT_ID");

        OAuth2AuthHandler oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(v, authProvider, "http://localhost:8201/callback");

        oauth2.setupCallback(proxyRouter.route("/callback"));
        proxyRouter.route("/*").handler(oauth2);
        proxyRouter.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").handler(ProxyHandler.create(httpProxy, 8200, "localhost"));
        
        proxyServer.requestHandler(proxyRouter).listen(8201);

The page authenticates fine but then fails when it redirects to the callback. I think the router for the proxy ends up in a loop.
Is it possible to make this work?

This could be a bug in the proxy itself.
I have filed https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-http-proxy/issues/101
